# Storing hierarchies/trees insdie a django model field?

Tags: django, django-models, database-design

First off, I know that there are packages like django-mptt and django-treebeard, but these don't look like what I am looking for. (There the goal seems to be to arrange all the model instances in a tree and the model has fields that encode the position of each instance. There is only one tree, nodes can be rearranged, deleted, or newly inserted.)

---

### The task:

**My goal, roughly speaking, is to have a model that stores trees. There are multiple trees to store in the database, and each instance of the model stores one of those trees.** I'll try to illustrate two different usage examples of different complexity. The first is probably easy to implement, the second... I don't know.
[Side question: Is there a name for what I am looking for? Searching for django+tree results in discussions of problems and solutions that are like django-mptt...]

---

### Simple case:

Consider models for chapters and books.

```py
class Chapter(Model):
    heading = CharField()
    text = TextField()

class Book(Model):
    name = CharField()
    structure = ???magic???
```

The chapter model stores the text parts of the book, so you'd have one instance holding heading and text on Topic A, another for Topic B, and so on. The book model has to store the structure of the book, i.e. which chapters go where. A book has multiple chapters and *a chapter can appear in more than one book*, e.g. imagine two book instances dedicated to the same subject, one is aimed at beginners and the other at experts. While these two books share some of the chapters, their structure is different:

```
Book Beginner
1. Introduction I
2. Topic TA
3. Topic TB
4. Topic TC
```

```
Book Expert
1. Topic TA
2. Topic TB
  2.1. Advanced Topic AT1
  2.2. Advanced Topic AT2
    2.2.1 Special Case SCX
3. Topic TC
4. Topic TD
```

I am using Django, REST Framework, and PostgreSQL. Is there an existing solution for storing the tree structure of the books in a database field? And if not, what would be a good way to go about it?
One of my thoughts was to use a JSONField and store nested arrays containing the primary keys of the chapter instances, i.e. `[I, TA, TB, TC]` for book1 and `[TA, TB, [AT2, AT2, [SCX]], TC, TD]` for book2. Reasonable or not?

---

### Complex case:

(This is probably what I really want to do. Kinda similar to above, but more meta; also the plausibility of the analogy to books and chapters breaks down a bit, but I'll use it anyway.)

```py
class Paragraph(Model):
    text = TextField()

class ChapterTree(Model):
    structure = ???magic???
    headings = ???magic???

class Book(Model):
    name = CharField()
    chapter_structure = ForeignKey(ChapterTree)
    contents = ???magic???
```

OK, this time a Paragraph is just a block of text; a ChapterTree stores a layout for the chapters, but no text aside from maybe all the corresponding chapter headings; a book has to use one of the predefined chapter structures and needs to specify which of the paragraphs should appear in each of the chapters. (I.e., two printed books with the same ChapterTree would always have the same table of contents, but could have different paragraphs as the main body of text.) Consider, e.g., two different ChapterTrees and 4 books derived from them:

```
tree1:                   BookI[chap_s=tree1]:       BookII[chap_s=tree1]:
1. Introduction I        1. Introduction            1. Introduction
2. Topic TA                par1                       par1
3. Topic TB              2. Topic TA                2. Topic TA
                           par2                       par2
                           par3                     3. Topic TB
                         3. Topic TB                  par4
                           par4                       par5
```

```
tree2:                       BookIII[chap_s=tree2]:        BookIV[chap_s=tree2]:
1. Topic TA                  1. Topic TA                   1. Topic TA
2. Topic TB                    par2                          par3
  2.1. Advanced AT1          2. Topic TB                   2. Topic TB
  2.2. Advanced AT2            par4                          2.1 Advanced AT1
    2.2.1 Special SCX          2.1 Advanced AT1                par6
                                 par6                          par8
                               2.2. Advanced AT2             2.2. Advanced AT2
                                 2.2.1 Special SCX             par9
                                   par7                        2.2.1 Special SCX
                                                                 par7
```

For the ChapterTree I could try storing the structure and the headings at the same time by using a JSONField of nested arrays of strings holding the headings `["Introduction I", "Topic TA", "Topic TB"]` for tree1 and `["Topic TA", "Topic TB", ["Advanced AT1", "Advanced AT2", ["Special SCX"]]]` for tree2. And then for the Book contents another JSONField with an array holding arrays of keys to the paragraph instances at each level, e.g., the four books would be `[[1], [2, 3], [4]]`, `[[1], [2], [4,5]]`, `[[2], [4], [6], [], [7]]`, and `[[3], [], [6,8], [9], [7]]`.

This idea is most likely terrible? There is nothing to enforce consistency; e.g., if one of the ChapterTree instances is modified by adding a new subchapter somewhere in the middle, all the books using this tree will be kinda broken (instead of ending up with an empty subchapter that can later be filled). I really hope there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Have you ever looked into a graph database? (This might be helpful). Not using another type of database that I don’t think integrates well with Django. Using a serializer from Django REST might make it so you can enforce the logic you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL, then Django's `JSONField` might serve you very well - [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield).

Comment: As I said, I am using PostgreSQL and am considering JSONField. But I don't know  what would be the best way to translate from my structure to JSON. In particular I don't even have an idea on whether the example implementation I sketched would even be sane.